# Is this possible to use $.getScript in firefox extension

Tags: javascript

Is this possible to use $.getScript in firefox extension.When i am calling it from html it is working but from Js file not able to execute

Comment: Why is this tagged with "Java"? I can not see any relation to "Java".

Comment: Well, the Java-Tag has been removed, so I will also remove my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load jQuery before using it's methods.
So, instead of having

```
<script src="myScript.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

you should have

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="myScript.js"></script>
```